# Limit calculating which involves integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

The limit which is required to calculate is as below:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1 } \frac {\int_{0}^{\ln^{2}(x)} e^{t^2} dt} {\sin^2(x-1)}.$$

I understand that I'm not expected to explicitly calculate the integral in the numerator  and I'm supposed to use integral by substitution or some similar ideas. However, I'm struggling to perform this idea in a way that I can estimate the numerator value.

I'd like if someone could help me to develop some intuition about it, thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to take an equivalent of the integral. You know $\ln(x)^2 \to 0$ when $x \to 1$. So the integral converges to 0. Moreover, $e^t \underset{t \to 0}{\to} 1 \neq 0$, So the integral term is equivalent to $\ln(x)^2$. This can be proved by hand in the following way :

Choose $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta >0$ such that $|e^{t^2}-1| \leq \epsilon$ for $0 \leq t < \delta$. Then you can control the integral for $|ln(x)^2| \leq \delta$, which happens because $ln(x)^2 \to 0$ for $x \to 1$. We get :

$(1-\epsilon) \ln(x)^2 \leq \int_0^{\ln(x)^2} e^(t^2) dt) \leq (1+\epsilon) \ln(x)^2$.

This shows that the integral term is equivalent to $\ln(x)^2$.
To finish, we need to find an equivalent of both $ln(x)^2$ and $sin(x-1)^2$ (because both tend to 0). These terms are both equivalent to $(x-1)^2$, using their Taylor series in 1 for example. You could also use L'Hopital's rule.
Conclusion : the limit is 1.

Answer (score 5):

Using
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 $$
and the MVT for integrals, one has
$$ \lim_{x\to 1 } \frac {\int_{0}^{\ln^{2}(x)} e^{t^2} dt} {\sin^2(x-1)}=\lim_{x\to 1 } \frac {\int_{0}^{\ln^{2}(x)} e^{t^2} dt} {(x-1)^2}\cdot\frac{(x-1)^2}{\sin^2(x-1)}=\lim_{x\to 1 } \frac {e^c\int_{0}^{\ln^{2}(x)} 1 dt} {(x-1)^2}=\lim_{x\to 1 } \frac {e^c\ln^{2}(x)} {(x-1)^2}=1 $$
where $c\in(0,\ln^2x)$.

Comment: This is so calculating-free and a more abstract way, thanks!